# OverflowError. Matplotlib log-scale

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a scatter plot on a log-log scale. Here is the code I have below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=[20,10])

s1=ax1.scatter(df_100['Publications2013'], df_100['totalcitations'], color='purple', label='hindex >99 percetile')
s2=ax1.scatter(df_99['Publications2013'], df_99['totalcitations'], color='blue', label='hindex 98-99 percentile' )

m,b = np.polyfit(df_all['Publications2013'],df_all['totalcitations'],1)
s8= ax1.plot(df_all['Publications2013'], m*df_all['Publications2013']+b, linestyle='-', linewidth='1', color='black', label='average citation/publications')

ax1.set_xlim(1,950)
ax1.set_ylim(1,122000)

ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')

plt.savefig("plots/pubs_vs_citations_zoom_log.png")
```

I get the following error:

```
OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks
```

When I remove the following two lines, the graph is plotted just fine but using a regular scale. How can I convert it to log scale? I'm not sure I understand what the error means.

```
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
```

Comment: How many data points do you have?

Comment: about 1.27 million. @DavidZwicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing:

```
m,b = np.polyfit(df_all['Publications2013'],df_all['totalcitations'],1)
s8= ax1.plot(df_all['Publications2013'], m*df_all['Publications2013']+b, linestyle='-', linewidth='1', color='black', label='average citation/publications')
```

It has to do with the `linestyle='-'`